# Having problems querying strings with _ in them - Python

Tags: python, split

I have a list of files

```
DIRLIST = ['201008190000_15201_NC.GZ', '201008190000_15202_NC.GZ', 
'201008190000_16203_NC.GZ', '201008200000_15201_NC.GZ', '201008200000_15202_NC.GZ', 
'201008200000_16203_NC.GZ',]
```

and I want to pick out certain files - say the two with 16203 in them.

My first thought was to use stringsplit in a for loop, but stringsplit doesn't give me anything beyond the _ in the strings - and I'm a little stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format of the filenames (datetime, underscore, id, underscore, letters, dot, GZ), then use this:

```
[d for d in DIRLIST if d.split('_')[1] == '16203']
```

The other proposition (with simple `if '16203' in dir` will let filenames like `201008162030_15201_NC_GZ` through too, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
filtered = [dir for dir in DIRLIST if '16203' in dir]
```

Comment: @sambasam: If you use this approach you need to change `'16203'` with `'_16203_'`, otherwise you could get false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'doesn't give me anything beyond the _ in the strings'

```
    >>> '201008190000_15201_NC.GZ'.split('_')
    ['201008190000', '15201', 'NC.GZ']
```

If all you need is a simple condition like you said, then Peter's suggestion will do just fine and is better that anything you would try with split.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
[dir for dir in files if re.search("(_16203_)", ",".join(DIRLIST))]
```